Strongswan - Connection successful but cannot access host in remote network
I am really confused. I have a VPN to a friends network that works on rare occasions, but most of the time strongswan connects successfully but I can't access anything on the remote network. This is my situation:

My Host (ubuntu): 192.168.178.52
My Router (FritzBox): 192.168.178.1
My friends Router (Swisscom): 192.168.1.1
The destination I want to reach: 192.168.1.148

I have the following configuration on my ubuntu Host:
connections {
  friend {
    version = 2
    remote_addrs = xxx.internet-box.ch
    vips = 0.0.0.0
    local {
      auth=psk
      id=roman
    }
    remote {
      auth=psk
      id=roman
    }
    children {
      vpn {
        # local_ts = 102.168.178.0/24
        remote_ts = 192.168.1.0/24
        # remote_ts = dynamic
        dpd_action = restart
        start_action = trap
      }
    }
  }
}

secrets {
  ike-1 {
    id-1=roman
    secret=xxxxxxxxxxx
  }
}

I run following commands:
$ swanctl --load-all
loaded ike secret 'ike-1'
no authorities found, 0 unloaded
no pools found, 0 unloaded
loaded connection 'friend'
successfully loaded 1 connections, 0 unloaded

Then I initiate the connection:
$ swanctl -i -c vpn
[IKE] establishing CHILD_SA vpn{146}
[ENC] generating CREATE_CHILD_SA request 2 [ SA No TSi TSr ]
[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.178.52[4500] to 85.7.x.x[4500] (252 bytes)
[NET] received packet: from 85.7.x.x[4500] to 192.168.178.52[4500] (204 bytes)
[ENC] parsed CREATE_CHILD_SA response 2 [ SA No TSi TSr ]
[CFG] selected proposal: ESP:AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA1_96/NO_EXT_SEQ
[IKE] CHILD_SA vpn{146} established with SPIs c0a290f4_i c8122518_o and TS 192.168.1.219/32 === 192.168.1.0/24
initiate completed successfully

But when I want to connect to 192.168.1.148 it times out most of the time. I know that the friends machine is up and running. It is his NAS. It is not rebooting. And it has a fixed IP address in his network.
Further analysis:
$ p route show table 220
192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.178.1 dev enp1s0 proto static src 192.168.1.219

$ ip route get 192.168.1.148
192.168.1.148 via 192.168.178.1 dev enp1s0 table 220 src 192.168.1.219 uid 1001 

$ ipsec statusall
Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.8.2, Linux 5.15.0-122-generic, x86_64):
  uptime: 2 days, since Oct 17 21:30:01 2024
  malloc: sbrk 2842624, mmap 0, used 1435984, free 1406640
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 27
  loaded plugins: charon aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm drbg attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark stroke vici updown eap-mschapv2 xauth-generic counters
Listening IP addresses:
  192.168.178.52
  2a02:200:2e01:54a0:9d83:2941:56e3:f2a2
  172.22.0.1
  172.24.0.1
  172.26.0.1
  172.18.0.1
  172.17.0.1
  172.21.0.1
  172.23.0.1
  172.20.0.1
  172.19.0.1
Connections:
       friend:  %any...xxxx.internet-box.ch  IKEv2
       friend:   local:  [roman] uses pre-shared key authentication
       friend:   remote: [roman] uses pre-shared key authentication
         vpn:   child:  dynamic === 192.168.1.0/24 TUNNEL
Routed Connections:
         vpn{1}:  ROUTED, TUNNEL, reqid 1
         vpn{1}:   0.0.0.0/0 === 192.168.1.0/24
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
       friend[135]: ESTABLISHED 16 minutes ago, 192.168.178.52[roman]...85.7.x.x[roman]
   friend[135]: IKEv2 SPIs: 1e75c069439e4117_i* f9053c4dd0c6b9ea_r, rekeying in 3 hours, pre-shared key reauthentication in 2 minutes
   friend[135]: IKE proposal: AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_2048
     vpn{145}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 136, ESP in UDP SPIs: c8ac1edd_i c07abc4a_o
     vpn{145}:  AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA1_96, 0 bytes_i, 0 bytes_o (0 pkts, 217s ago), rekeying in 38 minutes
     vpn{145}:   192.168.1.219/32 === 192.168.1.0/24
     vpn{146}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 136, ESP in UDP SPIs: c0a290f4_i c8122518_o
     vpn{146}:  AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA1_96, 0 bytes_i, 480 bytes_o (8 pkts, 217s ago), rekeying in 50 minutes
     vpn{146}:   192.168.1.219/32 === 192.168.1.0/24

Pinging the whole remote network results in no response at all:
$ sudo nping -c 1 --icmp --rate 100 192.168.1.148/24
SENT (0.0602s) ICMP [192.168.1.219 > 192.168.1.0 Echo request (type=8/code=0) id=6120 seq=1] IP [ttl=64 id=26107 iplen=28 ]
SENT (0.0708s) ICMP [192.168.1.219 > 192.168.1.2 Echo request (type=8/code=0) id=9726 seq=1] IP [ttl=64 id=26107 iplen=28 ]

...
SENT (2.6199s) ICMP [192.168.1.219 > 192.168.1.255 Echo request (type=8/code=0) id=21108 seq=1] IP [ttl=64 id=26107 iplen=28 ]
SENT (2.6299s) ICMP [192.168.1.219 > 192.168.1.255 Echo request (type=8/code=0) id=21108 seq=1] IP [ttl=64 id=26107 iplen=28 ]
...
Statistics for host 192.168.1.255:
 |  Probes Sent: 1 | Rcvd: 0 | Lost: 1  (100.00%)
 |_ Max rtt: N/A | Min rtt: N/A | Avg rtt: N/A
Raw packets sent: 256 (7.168KB) | Rcvd: 0 (0B) | Lost: 256 (100.00%)
Nping done: 256 IP addresses pinged in 3.72 seconds

On my side there is a UFW running. Disabling the UFW by sudo systemctl stop ufw does not change the result of nping.
I have no idea what I could try next. I am very thankful if someone could point me in to any meaningful direction.

Does the remote computer you attempt to connect to have a route back to you?

That is a good question. I would think it would take the default gateway which is my friends router. I built the vpn with that router. So I guess it knows that it should route it through the tunnel to me.

Can you ping that router? Is there any firewall rules?

Thank you for your reply! I just added the result of nping in the question. I can't ping any host. Not even the IP address that I am supposed to sit on. Disabling ufw seams to have no effect.

According to the traffic stats in the status output, there is outbound traffic but no inbound traffic. So the problem is most likely at the other end. Could be a routing or firewall issue there (or because your virtual IP is from the remote subnet, an issue with ARP).
